# Schema URL error - Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, xsd

am trying out the petcare spring sample program but i get the following error in servlet-context

```
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not 
 find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'petcare:resources'.
```

The spring-petcare-3.0.xsd is located on ***org.springframework.samples.petcare.util.config*** package under ***src/main/resources***. How do i change URL schema to point here?

Answer (score 1):

The sample works for me.

Have you built and deployed it correctly?  Specifically can you check for the existence of file `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring.schemas` in the deployed webapp, which contains the line

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/samples/petcare/util/config/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd
```

It is this, which indicates to the webapp, the location of the xsd file

Comment: Under WEB-INF/classes/ META-INF does not exist. only application.properties file ... on eclipse this is under the Web Folder 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF'  ...... EDIT: No, spring.schemas exist under src/main/resources. I'm using springsource Tool Suite so the setup is a bit different to eclipse /EDIT

Comment: <petcare:resources /> is what's causing the problem

Comment: @sonx - this tag is defined in the xsd file.  Perhaps you should try building and running it outside the IDE, which is what I did