# need help installing and running spring petcare sample app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, xsd

I need help getting [the spring **PETCARE** application](https://github.com/rajgowda/spring-petcare) to run in my eclipse/tomcat installation using the egit and m2e plugins, which I already not installed on my machine.  Note this is **NOT** the spring petclinic application.  Here is what I have done so far:

```
1.) I downloaded the spring PETCARE sample into eclipse kepler  
    using the eclipse egit plugin
2.) I then converted it to a maven project in eclipse and did  
    a maven update using the m2e plugin.
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error in the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml` indicating that `petcare:resources` is not being found:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'petcare:resources'.
```

I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545837/schema-url-error-spring-3-0) and then located the `spring.schemas` file in the path `myproject/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.schemas` in my eclipse project.

`spring.schemas` contains the following one line of code only:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/samples/petcare/util/config/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd
```

Can anyone show me how to fix this problem so that the error message is resolved and my application can compile?

Even explicit, step-by-step instructions for how to download and install the application into eclipse using egit and m2e plugins would be sufficient.  We can start from scratch correctly instead of backtracking from the error I am currently getting.

---

**Note**: In addition to the contents of the accepted answer, I also needed to make sure that eclipse was using a JDK and not a JRE in order for the application to launch successfully in eclipse using Run As..Run on Server.

Comment: Well, that is because this schema really doesnt exist. 
Try accessing 

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd
and you will get a 404.

Comment: ^Yeah, the schema doesn't exists.
I was able to find spring-petcare-3.0.xsd on other location, try it: https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petcare/trunk/src/main/resources/org/springframework/samples/petcare/util/config/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd

Comment: try using file://<full path of the xsd>

Comment: ok. this is what has been done in the petcare application. Look at this link. `http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-schema` Ideally, you should be able to access your extended `xsd` using the URL `http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd` since, this is the one which is mentioned in your spring.handlers and spring.schemas location

Comment: please show us the xml based definition of your `servlet-context.xml`

Comment: actually, have you tried to do a build or a maven clean install ignoring validation error by eclipse? in the meanwhile i will try to clone the repo and check locally

Comment: If i'm not wrong, this is not url but just uri. It's just to identify your xsd. Java provide a catalog resolver and it could work without any internet connection. So, this xsd is in your classpath and you give us the location. If i'm right, try to replace the URL `http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd` with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/util/config/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd`. It should probably work.

Comment: @CodeMed : Try to validate your project after with a right click on your project and validate. I don't think your need to upadte your maven project. Maybe a clean project > before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the petcare namespace is that it's not available online by following the schema location URL.

Spring gets around this at runtime using the spring.schemas file, but eclipse does not know about this file nor how to use it to find XSD's. The solution is to configure the petcare namespace manually in eclipse, using the XML Catalog.

Go to Preferences, and in there in the XML Catalog section configure the namespace like this:

[image]

In location put the full hard drive path to the xsd file `spring-petcare-3.0.xsd`, choose key type `Schema location` and as key put the full URL for the XSD: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/petcare/spring-petcare-3.0.xsd`

For confirming that it works, right click on the servlet-context.xml file and click validate. The file should no longer be in red.

This is an example of the application looks running:
[image]

And this is the URL to access it:

```
http://localhost:20010/users/signin
```

To run it, these are the steps:

create a file named context.xml in webapp/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/"/>
```

- add this to your pom.xml in the build/plugins section:

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <port>20010</port>
              <path>/</path>              
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- run the application from the command line with:

  mvn clean install tomcat7:run-war  -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Running log:

```
INFO : org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2
INFO : org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer - started doctorMail.adapter
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 0
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1661 ms
Feb 05, 2014 12:11:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-20010"]
```

- access the application with the URL above
- you can create a maven launch configuration in eclipse to launch it as a maven task

Comment: I have added context.xml

Comment: does it work from maven? If so it's a problem in the server that needs to be cleaned up/reinstalled. If maven gives the same error, it's the file encoding that is corrupted. Try to redownload it and run the app without editing it, clean eveything, etc. The file should be UTF-8 encoding, maybe your eclipse is not set to that encoding and the file got corrupted with some edit. In any case it's for sure specific on your local environment as I confirm that the file in git runs OK.

Comment: On the dialog box of the third edit, on the text box named goals, put these goals: ' clean install tomcat7:run-war', click the skip tests checkbox. The maven runtime is set on the snasphot to maven embedded, that should work, but if not click 'Configure' and point to your local maven installation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46792/discussion-between-jhadesdev-and-codemed)

Comment: I deleted all the references to JREs in eclipse and then cleaned all the projects in the eclipse workspace, so that eclipse is forced to use a JDK instead of a JRE.  In combination with your advice to set the default maven instance to the external maven, this enables the app to launch successfully from eclipse's Run as..Run on Server.  I will thus now mark this question as answered and award the bounty.  Thank you for all of your educational help.

Comment: I have another question about annotations for a class that manages metadata in a spring application.  Are you willing to help me out with it also? Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592892/spring-annotation-for-entity-that-links-other-entities