# spring annotation for entity that links other entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am writing calendar functionality into a spring mvc application.  I have a `calendar.jsp` which provides a view of `appointments`, which in turn are associated with `providers` and `customers`.

My underlying MySQL database has tables for `appointments`, `providers`, and `customers`.  But `calendar` is an abstraction for the user interface.  The `Calendar` class does not have an associated table in the database, but the `Calendar` class does have a `List` of all `appointments` and a `list` of all `providers`, etc.  I use `@Entity` annotation for `appointments`, `providers`, and `customers`.

What spring annotation should I use for the `Calendar` class?

I need to be able to reference `calendar.providers` and `calendar.appointments`, etc. from `calendar.jsp`.

Here is [a link to an example of a similar class that uses Roo annotation](https://github.com/rajgowda/spring-petcare/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petcare/appointments/AppointmentCalendar.java).

I would prefer to avoid using Roo.  It would be nice to be able to use the base spring framework distribution.  My app uses Spring and Hibernate.  I would like to avoid adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Showing us what you have done so far would help alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've missed something here but are you sure you're not overcomplicating things? If you want to expose a populated `Calendar` instance in your jsp, then after populating it just add it to the model in your controller method.

Provided that `Calendar` has Java bean style properties for its `providers` and `appointments` then you can use dotted notation to access this data in the jsp.

For example, without seeing any controller code:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/calendar")
    public String showCalendar(Model model) {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendar() // Or whatever you do to create it
        model.addAttribute("calendar", calendar);
        return "calendar";
    }

    ...
}
```

And then in calendar.jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="appointment" items="${calendar.appointments}">
    <c:out value="${appointment.time}" /> <%-- Access the fields in the usual manner --%>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: +1 and thank you for educating me. I am pursuing this approach.  I will wait to mark the answer as accepted until I get it working.

Comment: No problem. I think Peter has already answered your subsequent question.

Comment: After getting the calendar functionality to run, I found that my patient management functionality does not run when I click on the link to load it in browser.  I am wondering if the new problem is related to how the calendar code is set up.  Do you mind taking a look at it and trying to resolve it?  Here is the link to the new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691629/hibernate-could-not-deserialize